# CSS transition not applying to <a> tag

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

I am trying to create a transition for an "a" tag using the below code (written in SASS), however, the transition doesn't seem to apply. On hover, it immediately adds the bottom border and when removing the cursor, there is a second delay before removing the border without a transition.

```
a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        left: 1em;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 500;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: white 0px solid;
        transition: all 2s ease-in-out;

        &:hover {
           border-bottom: white 1px solid;
        }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition from 0px to 1px is just one step. If you want to let the border appear try to use the opacity of the border. Like:

```
border-bottom: rgba(255,255, 255,0) 1px solid;
```

and on hover:

```
border-bottom: rgba(255,255,255,1) 1px solid;
```

```css
a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        left: 1em;
        color: red;
        font-weight: 500;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: rgba(255,0,0,0) 1px solid;
        transition: all 2s ease-in-out;

       
}

a:hover {
            border-bottom: rgba(255,0,0,1) 1px solid;
           
        }
```

```html
<a href="#">A Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question, I tried wrapping this "a" in a div and applying the border transition to that instead. However, the :hover styles for the div never apply. See this example: https://codepen.io/slatifi/pen/rNygOgZ. Do you know why?

Comment: @Saif: Works for me but its white :D try rgba(255,0,0)

Comment: Oh in my main project it didn't work as I had position:absolute applied. After I removed that it worked!